# How to delete the iOS7 install package on iPhone?

Tags: ios

Some days ago I realized, that Apple automatically stored the iOS7 install package on my iPhone 4S with iOS6. The package uses about 2 GB of free space, which is inacceptable for me.

How can I locate and delete this file?

Comment: How did you found that out?

Answer (score 1):

I did not have this issue and so didn't have to deal with it. But there is a [solution posted on the Apple Discussion Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23278869#23278869) that you could try. If it doesn't work, you could follow up there (and subscribe to that thread to get updates). Make sure you have a backup (along with Time Machine backups of your previous backup and this one).

Here are the instructions from that post (with better formatting and some typo fixes):

> **Part 2. Delete iOS 7 firmware downloaded automatically:**
>   **Method A:**
>   If you have backup in iTunes, recover it. (I didn't test this method, so it's on your own risk.)
>
> **Method B:**
>
> - Open **Settings > General > Software Update**
> - Tap **Install Now**.
> - There will be a prompt that says "Verifying update...".
> - Wait until this prompt disappears, there will be a spinning wheel on a black background. Immediately press and hold both of the power and home buttons at the same time.
> - DO NOT release the power and home buttons for about 10 seconds.
> - Your device will reboot. It's done. The automatically downloaded firmware will have been deleted.

Comment: "The automatically downloaded firmware will have been deleted." Till a few days later when iOS consults Apple's servers and grabs it again. There is no fix. Either Apple has to implement an option to stop downloading the updates, or iOS will always grab them if they are not there. Deleting them will only provide temporary relief.